# TypeScript cannot identify default functions like console.log()

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am new to TypeScript (in Vue3 project with Vite) and what annoys me is, that there are a lot of default JavaScript functions, or objects that TypeScript cannot identify such as:

- console.log()
- setTimeout()
- clearTimeout()
- the type of $event

I don't get an error when running the app with `npm run dev`, but when I run it with `npm run lint`

Also my IDE (Jetbrains Webstorm) doesnt like it and therefore marks it with the following error message:
`TS2584: Cannot find name 'console'. Do you need to change your target library?`

Or for setTimeout:
`TS2304: Cannot find name 'setTimeout'.`

I tried to install the types with:
`npm install @types/node --save-dev`

And also included the following in my `tsconfig.config.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["node"],
    "lib": ["ES6", "DOM"]
 },
```

But for some reason it won't work, even though this is the answer to my problem I that I have found in many stack overflow questions or in other articles.

I really don't wan't to supress it with //@ts-ignor, since it doesn't feel right and eslint does not like it

Comment: What does _"TypeScript cannot identify"_ mean? In CLI? In IDE? Does it throw an error?

Comment: Do you get an error when starting your application? If yes, can you paste it, maybe it's just eslint, because this type of error happen in the browser.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply.
I am using Vite and not the vue cli. My IDE does not like it, I don't get an error when starting the application, only when I run `npm run lint`
The error my IDE is displaying me looks like the following:
`TS2584: Cannot find name 'console'. Do you need to change your target library?`